# Advance Excel formula help needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a spreadsheet of liquid products in column A.  Each product has 6 sizes in ML listed in column B (6 rows).  In columns C - F I have different companys that sell the product.  I have listed their price for each size in the company's column. So there are a total of up to 23 different cells to analyze per product For example:  Company A sells 3ML for $5.84, Company B sells 4ML for 9.87, etc.  I want to have excel calculate the lowest price per ML and the highest price per ML in the background and highlight the price in cell related to each of these.  So there would be two highlights per 24 cells.  Then I would need to be able to copy this to move to the next product.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the screenshot below.

To calculate the minimum price per unit, use

```
=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$13=A2,$C$2:$E$13/$B$2:$B$13,1000))
```

To calculate the maxium price per unit, use

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$13=A2,$C$2:$E$13/$B$2:$B$13,0))
```

Both are array formulas and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> when you edit the cell.

You can set up conditional formatting with these formulas. Green highlights the vendor and product with the minimum price per unit with a conditional format using this formula:

```
=C2/$B2=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$13=$A2,$C$2:$E$13/$B$2:$B$13,1000))
```

Red highlights the vendor and product with the maximum price per unit with this formula in the conditional formatting rule:

```
=C2/$B2=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$13=$A2,$C$2:$E$13/$B$2:$B$13,0))
```

Used in conditional formatting you don't need to array-enter the formulas. Conditional formatting formulas are automatically treated as array formulas.

[image]